# I am comparing two assets Rolling 10 Year Sharpe Ratios. I want to know what percentage increase in Sharpe Ratio is meaningful?

Tags: sharpe-ratio

If Asset A is having 35% higher Sharpe Ratio than Asset B is that significant? Or should I consider that only if Asset A is having 50% higher Sharpe Ratio than Asset B.